# How i can popup a context menu in a treeview but just in some particular treenodes?

Tags: delphi

I have a TPopupMenu associated with a  TTreeView, but i now want to invoke (popup) the menu  only when the user click in a particular node. So how i can popup a context menu in a treeview but just in some particular treenodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `Handled` parameter from the [`OnContextPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnContextPopup) event. By setting this parameter to True you will suppress the context menu to display. The following code shows how to get the `TTreeNode` from the cursor position passed into the [`OnContextPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnContextPopup) event and it displays the popup menu only when you right click over the `TTreeNode` different from the top one.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if TreeView1.GetNodeAt(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y) = TreeView1.TopItem then
    Handled := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
  var node : TTreeNode;
begin
  node := TreeView1.GetNodeAt(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y);
  if not Assigned (node) then
    Abort;
end;
```

Comment: There's a better answer since almost two years.